# Source to destination message delivering without any network call or chat server client

Tags: python, python-3.x

Is there any way to make one-way text communication from `source` to `destination`.

There should be two scripts `source.py` and `destination.py` if I run `source.py` in `Terminal 1` and `destination.py` on `Terminal 2, Terminal 3` .
Then following behaviour is expected after running both scripts-
As soon as any key is pressed on `Terminal 1` , the same key should
be printed on `Terminal 2 and Terminal 3`.

but the condition is, This process should not involve any network call.and this is not a chat server client problem.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You need to be a lot more specific. What operating system? Are loopback sockets or Unix domain sockets allowable? Does one of the programs launch the other?

Comment: @DanielPryden , please check edits, ` loopback sockets or Unix domain sockets not allowable`. OS- ubuntu

Comment: UDS is the normal way to solve this sort of problem. Why can't you use it? (Note that UDS does not involve a network connection.)

Comment: Next best option would probably be to just use a filesystem file. Have one process open it for writing and the other open for reading.

Comment: Why is UDS not allowed? UDS doesn't involve the network at all, so what is allowed? Is filesystem allowed? mmap? shm? pipes? pty? dbus? What system calls are allowed?